# how to change the value of label in slider (material ui)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

code sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-worker-kxse3?file=/src/App.js

i want the labels in bubble to show the same value as text(3,5,7,10)

Comment: Set value also to the same numbers?

Comment: @Vishnudev value is the cuttoff percent on slider for position(like 0 means the starting point and 100 means the end point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the `label` instead of `index` on your `valueLabelFormat`. Change it to

```js
function valueLabelFormat(value) {
  return marks.find((mark) => mark.value === value).label;
}
```

[image: Edit interesting-kalam-5vq67]